# CartThrob: subscription discount coupon development

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart, subscriptions, discounts, coupon-code

Bit of an odd/exceptional issue but we are using CartThrobn on a site to sell subscriptions. We want to be able to offer a reduced price subscription if a certain coupon code is added at checkout.

We are currently applying the subscription to a specific, user-generated entry via the `subscription_plan_id` and `subscription` attributes of `{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}`.

I'm guessing we'd need to write our own discount/coupon class but not sure then how we'd then essentially switch the plan to another on submission of a specific coupon code.

Any thoughts how this might be achieved?

Cheers

Cole

Comment: Wouldn't that be the way that coupons normally work? You would create a coupon entry for the discount and if added to the cart (by entering the code) then it would subtract an amount from the total.

Comment: This would be for life though, eg so a discount based on the plan cost.

Comment: Ah I see. So if the normal price is £10 per month, the discount is for £2. They would pay £8 per month, every month. I'm actually surprised it doesn't work like that anyway.